# Can I use Elasticsearch as a datasource(input) for Grafana?

Tags: elasticsearch, influxdb, grafana

Can I use elasticsearch as a input datasource for Grafana. I want to store the data in influxDb after that. 
What would the grafana config file look like?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grafana 1.9 does not support elasticsearch as a datasource. 
You may try to using Version v2.0. This version allows to set elasticsearch like a datasource.